# Convergence to gradient in limit of variance

Tags: machine-learning, probability, deep-learning, generative-models, gan

I came across this equation in the original GAN paper (pg 2 https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5423-generative-adversarial-nets.pdf):
$$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0}
\nabla_{\bf x} \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I)}[{f({\bf x} + \epsilon)}] = \nabla_{\bf x} f({\bf x}).$$

Is this a well known result, or easy to prove? Not sure how to proceed beyond the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0}
\nabla_{\bf x} \mathbb{E}_{\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I)}[{f({\bf x} + \epsilon)}]
&= \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0}
\int_{\epsilon} \nabla_{\bf x} f({\bf x} + \epsilon) p(\epsilon) d \epsilon \end{align*}.
$$

Any tips or sources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is true when $f$ has a continuous gradient, in which case $$\lim_{h \rightarrow \vec0} \nabla_x f(x+h) = \nabla_x f(x)$$ which is equivalent to $$\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \nabla_x f(x+\sigma z) = \nabla_x f(x)$$ for any value of $z$.

Then $$\begin{align}&\quad\ \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \nabla_x \mathbb{E}_\epsilon \left[f(x+\epsilon )\right] \\
&= \lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \nabla_x \mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)}\left[f(x + \sigma z)\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)}\left[\lim_{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \nabla_x f(x + \sigma z) \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_z \left[ \nabla_x f(x)\right] \\
& = \nabla_x f(x)\end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) Of course, some further technicalities on $f$ are needed to formally exchange the limit and the expectation, but this is surely the level of technicality at which the GAN paper was thinking about it.